# Is there a category with a subobject classifier but which is not finitely complete?

Tags: ct.category-theory, examples, topos-theory

This is a reverse of the question [“Is there a finitely complete category with terminal object but NO subobject classifier?”](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14815/is-there-a-finitely-complete-category-with-terminal-object-but-no-subobject-class) From [“An informal introduction to topos theory”](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.5647) by Tom Leinster I learned that there is 3 definitions of a subobject classifier in some category C:

1. where we directly work with morphisms of C: for every monomorphism there exists a characteristic morphism etc.;
2. a terminal object in the category of monomorphisms and pullback squares;
3. the functor Sub is representable.

In order to make sense of (3) we need Sub which is defined via pullbacks in C. (3) requires C to have pullbacks. But (1) and (2) do not, though they imply existence of the terminal object. Is there a category with a subobject classifier and which is not finitely complete? (AFAIK subobject classifier → terminal object → (have pullbacks ↔ have finite limits = is finitely complete).)

Answer (score 14):

Yes: take the full subcategory of $Set$ whose objects are sets of cardinality 2 or less.